# Why are points given for editing?

Tags: discussion, reputation, editing, suggested-edits

I think only badges should be given for editing and **not points**?
So, why are points given for editing? Many users make points by just editing.

Comment: Well there is a badge for editing (copy-editor) and you only get 2 rep for the 1000 firsts (accepted) edits or if you have less than $2000$ rep. The badge illuminator also involves some edits.

Comment: Actually, you can only get 1000 rep with edits (and not 1000 edits with 2 rep).
Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82020/why-is-there-a-limit-on-edit-reputation-reward

Comment: Points are not given for editing after your reputation reaches $2000$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several badges involving post edits:
- [Editor](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3/editor)
- [Strunk and white](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white)
- [Copy-editor](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor)
- [Excavator](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/128/excavator)
- [Archaeologist](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/127/archaeologist)
- [Explainer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/440/explainer)
- [Refiner](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/441/refiner)
- [Illuminator](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/442/illuminator)

From the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/262749) (emphasize is mine):

> To *promote good edits*, a user who suggests an edit to someone else’s post will get +2 reputation points when that edit suggestion is approved. You do not get the reputation bonus if the edit is automatically approved, whether this is because you are editing your own post, you are editing a community wiki post, or you have at least 2000 reputation and all of your edits are auto-approved. Also, you are limited to a *maximum of 1000 reputation points earned from edits*.

I think [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82023/262749) is also worth mentioning (emphasize is mine):

> [...] You can get up to 1000 as *an encouragement to get familiar with the edit system and so that you will get in the habit of doing it*, but you won't get rep forever for the work.. It's more of a one time thing (or 500 times thing in this case).

Comment: *"Get them hooked on editing, and then let them do it for free"*. Sounds like a solid drug dealing strategy! :P