# Why don't I get reputation points for edits anymore?

Tags: support, editing, reputation, suggested-edits

It has now been 3 days. Although I edit questions, I do not get reputation points anymore. The edits have not been rejected. Any hints, please?

Comment: To me the tag ([meta-tag:support]) seems more suitable for this question than ([meta-tag:feature-request]). I do not in your post see any suggestion for a new feature that should be implemented.

Comment: Related: [Editing answers does not give reputation anymore](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2230).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to earn at most 1000 reputation points through [suggested edits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/suggested-edits/info). See:

- [Why is there a limit on edit reputation reward?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82020)
- "Can I earn reputation?" section in: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)
- End of the first paragraph in: [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788#21789)
- [Why are points given for editing?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23595)

You can check your reputation breakdown at this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation. If you see at the end "earned 1000 reputation from suggested edits", that means you're already at maximum.

Also your profile shows (in the activity tab) [586 edit suggestions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/482116/dmtri?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and [570 edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/482116/dmtri?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Which means you're very likely beyond 500 approved edits, corresponding to 1000 reputation points.

I will add that as soon as you're [over 2000 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) points, you can edit posts without needing an approval by other users. For a direct edit (as opposed to suggested edits, which is reviewed) a user doesn't get 2 reputation points - even if they have still less than 1000 reputation points from suggested edits.